# What was the age difference between Roland, Cuthbert, and Alain?

Tags: stephen-king, the-dark-tower

Roland's childhood friends and fellow gunslingers were named Alain and Cuthbert.  What was the age difference between the three?

Comment: In Wizard and Glass, Roland remembers a holiday long ago when he and Cuthbert were "no more than seven years old", which might suggest that Roland and Cuthbert were born only months apart.

Answer (score 2):

Read "Wizards And Glass". Roland tells the story of Susan Delgado. They're all approximately the same age, around 14, but at the time Roland is the only one who has passed the Gunslinger trial.

Comment: Approximately I know.  I want specifics.

Comment: @WadCheber I've had a hunt around and couldn't find anything more specific; this may be the best you can get without asking King specifically.

Comment: I think that if you read "Song Of Susannah" carefully, it does give the age, but doesn't give actual birth dates.

Comment: I've read it.  I don't remember Cuthbert and Alain being in it.  It's mostly Susannah and Mia having a demon baby, and everyone else trying to find Susannah.  If you could find the quotes with the ages and add them, I would upvote and accept your answer.  As it sits, you basically said what I already knew and told me to read a book I read for the second time last week.

Comment: Just checked my kindle edition of Song of Susannah - Cuthbert is mentioned a few times, Alain twice.  None of the mentions relate to their ages.

Comment: I'm sorry, I quoted the wrong book. It's "Wizards And Glass" when Roland tells the story of Susan Delgado. I should have checked first.